# D3 nested objects should be different colors

Tags: csv, d3.js, nested, data-visualization

I'm creating a line graph in which the area under the line is colored based on a variable `rank` that is not taken into account with plotting with `date` and `close`. I'm using `d3.nest()` to chunk data based on the `rank` and then looping through `dataGroup` and plotting each entry with a random color.

Based on this thought process, each of the dataGroups should be a different color, but when it plots, I only get one random color for the whole plot.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tx4J60fGzSl658y4hGMU?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.area {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    var dataGroup = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            return d.rank;
        })
        .entries(data);

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area);
        });

    svg.selectAll(".area")
        .style("fill",function() {
          return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";
        })

    // Draw the x Grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add the text label for the X axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                             (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

    // Add the white background to the y axis label for legibility
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text("Price ($)");

    // Add the text label for the Y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Price ($)");

    // Add the title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))     
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Price vs Date Graph");

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just by the way, is there a reason why you don't use `enter().append` and `.exit()` type patterns?

Comment: Not a good reason. I'm new with D3 and this is working. If there are better ways to do things, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Im new too and I've burnt my fingers a few times, but the main thing I've worked out is that d3 is **declarative** and **data-driven**. Every time I forget that I get into trouble. The idea is to declare the binding and entering and exiting behaviour of how the graphic elements respond to the data and then leave them alone and drive it from the data. Check out the wiki anyway, there are some excellent tutorials, but for sure I recomend figuring out how `enter().append()` `enter().insert()` and `.exit()` work with the data join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the complete dataset (data) to each area element. As a result, all areas are on top of each other and the fill results in just showing the top most area path.
Instead in your dataGroup.forEach() you need to bind just the data corresponding to the rank:

...svg.append("path").datum(d.values)....

Comment: Got it!! Thank you. I've been working on this for days!!